# How can I use Webpack to create bundle for a Rest API Express NodeJS Server

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

Hope you are all well :)

I was working on a REST API server with Nodejs and after completing an alpha version, I wanted to create a bundle for it with build tools, Although I succeeded at some point in bundling the app still could not make the Express Rest API scripts to be bundled. As I am not really experienced with the Webpack, I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong and there has to be a way to do this. You can also see my my webpack.config.js, .babelrc and package.json below:

**Webpack.config.js**

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var module_dir = `${__dirname}/node_modules`;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './index.js',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
           presets: ['env', 'stage-0']
        }
    }]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
          __dirname + '/node_modules'
        ]
  }
}
```

**.Babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/env"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nodemon index.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --progress"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "log",
    "npm",
    "node",
    "rest",
    "api",
    "debug",
    "bug"
  ],
  "author": "Mehdi Roshan Fekr",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

I also have read this article about using express with webpack but I couldn't implement it properly, which I think one the reason for, is it is for a ReactJS app:
[How can I use webpack with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102035/how-can-i-use-webpack-with-express)

**----Updates-----**

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env' from 'C:\Projects\# App Projects\Qcentic-Log'
- Did you mean "@babel/env"?
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (C:\Projects\# App Projects\Qcentic-Log\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:58:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (C:\Projects\# App Projects\Qcentic-Log\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePreset (C:\Projects\# App Projects\Qcentic-Log\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:58:10)
    at loadPreset (C:\Projects\# App Projects\Qcentic-Log\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:77:20)
    at createDescriptor (C:\Projects\# App Projects\Qcentic-Log\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at items.map (C:\Projects\# App Projects\Qcentic-Log\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const CustomModule = require('./CustomModule');
app.use(express.json());
//My Endpoints...
app.listen(80, () => console.log('Listening on port 80'));
```

Comment: To bundle for nodejs, you need to add `target: "node"` to your config. And if that is not enough, please do post the errors/warning or anything that can help debugging, otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated the question and added the index.js general structure and the error that I get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are passing babel config directly to the loader, you do not need the `.babelrc` file. Also, you are using babel v7, so below is the updated config (your config and package.json contain mixed packages of babel v6 and v7 and they don't work together):

```
module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: [
                    [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        {
                            targets: {
                                node: "8.10"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [
            __dirname + '/node_modules'
        ]
    }
}
```

1. Note that I removed `@babel/polyfill`, you don't need it for the server environment (I am sure because I am also bundling my server code with webpack and never needed it).
2. Make sure to set the version of `node` to whatever your target version is.
3. Also note that `query` is a very old way of passing options to webpack loaders, so I updated it to the new syntax, using `options`. And it is always best to pass full name of babel plugins, e.g.: `@babel/preset-env` instead of just `env`. The old way of resolving plugin names would generate a `babel-preset-env` based on `env`, but since babel v7 they restructured the project to "scoped packages", thus the `@babel/` prefix, so best to specify full name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the bundle was successful but I get error when I try to use it on apache:

I did make a very simple html for it like below:

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      Hellow
    <script src="./app.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

but it does not load anything

Comment: app.bundle.js:88 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: I removed the api endpoints and just put a simple console log in the index but still got the same error

Comment: Once bundled, you need to run your express server like `node app.bundle.js`. It will start your express server and the API will be ready to receive requests.

Comment: yes but server is based on php and is running uner apache, these api  endpoints are going to be an addition like a micro service there and if it is possible they should be callable from browser directly with out running a new node

Comment: APIs can not be run in the browser. What you are trying to do is including a javascript bundle containing your API in the browser.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I mis explained the running concept of the nodejs app

What I meant was somthing like this:
http://www.codingtricks.biz/run-nodejs-application-apache/

Also thank you so much, your a legend :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189949/discussion-between-pavel-denisjuk-and-mehdi-roshan-fekr).

Comment: @PavelDenisjuk Thank you man! +1! The only change I had to do is in my code. I was getting "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'", then have done what's said here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-273890888: change 'module.exports' for 'export default' and it worked as a charm. I believe that's not a solution but a workaround. Any chance you know why and how to solve it without replacing 'module.exports'?

Comment: @Rodrigo.A92 without looking at your code I can't tell you what's wrong, but most likely it's an issue with mixing import/export and module.exports. Use one of the systems, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @PavelDenisjuk Thanks for the answer. I'll investigate further and if I'm not able to find a proper answer, will post a new thread. Thanks for the help!